# Rails DB design: Albums and albumless images with JSONB and PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, database-design, ruby-on-rails-5, image-gallery

I am designing a historical buildings website where an user can upload multiple images using Shrine. I am trying to come up with a DB design which would enable me to satisfy these requirements of mine:

- An user can create album. This album **must** belong to a building
- An album can contain arbitrary number of images
- **The issue: some images do not have to belong to an album.**
  I should be able to upload an albumless image and use it in a building description or in a blog text where it does not make sense to put it in any album. There will not be any `album_id` column in `Images` table. Galleries will get their image IDs from JSONB column of an image.

Solutions I could think of:

1. **Polymorphic images.** This would insert columns `imageable_type` and `imageable_id` in Images table to store the parent model and its record ID. To store ID of an album where this image belongs to, I could avoid using a DB column `album_id` in `Images` table and leverage my existing JSONB column in `Images` table and put it there instead (I'm putting image description and other stuff there and I want to keep it that way).
   Pros: `imageable_type` can be `Building, Blog, Album` - it covers everything I need.
   Cons: feels kinda messy and weird
2. Not using any implicit ActiveRecord relationship at all (no has_many, belongs_to) because I do not have `album_id` for single images in blogs and building descriptions. Joining manually using image IDs in JSONB columns.

I'd really appreciate any design ideas here. Brainstorming on!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for anyone trying to decide, I used the polymorphic images. If an image is added to a gallery, its imageable_type is Gallery which adds them nicely to an appropriate gallery.

Thanks for helping.